# Can the await block code be outside of the async function containing the await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```
setInterval(() => {
  // do some stuff
}, 1000)

const foo = async () => {
  const res = await api_call();
  const do_stuff();
}

await foo();
```

Will the `foo` function block the `setInterval` when its callback is due to be executed?

Comment: Yes. JavaScript is single-threaded. So if `api_call()` finishes before the next interval time, `do_stuff()` will run to completion. If the next interval occurs first, it will run to completion before `do_stuff()` can run.

Comment: Actually, will callback in the setInterval execute on schedule if the `api_call` is still running?

Comment: They'll both execute. But only one can execute at a time.

Comment: Do you understand what single-threaded means?

Comment: "will callback in the setInterval execute on schedule if the api_call is still running" No. You only get one javascript thing running at any given time in any given context. Transfer of control only happens in specific places. (There's a lot of things that can make this confusing. For example, parts of certain built-in functions, like `fetch`, don't operate entirely in javascript. As well, there are other contexts you could run in such as service workers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `api_call` returns a promise, the `await` function effectively 'pauses' the `foo` function until something causes the promise to resolve.

If 1000ms pass before that happens, the timeout code executes first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question can be down to the prioritization between the callback of `setInterval` and foo() function under single thread